# Win7 USB mouse driver no longer handling KVM switching

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse, kvm-switch

I have been using a 2-port USB KVM switch for years without problems, but in the last few days when I switch back to my win-7 PC the mouse is not working correctly; the mouse hover events register and the cursor changes, e.g. resize cursors etc, but I can't interact with anything via the mouse buttons, and cannot raise the taskbar.

The only quick-fix is doing a ctrl-alt-del then selecting Cancel, which seems to kick the drivers back into shape.  However I don't want to be doing this every time I switch between PC's.

Does anybody have a guide on getting the USB mouse drivers to remain active or to reload correctly after the KVM switch changes over?

I suspect a windows update may have changed something, tho why they would have to break previously acceptable hardware is beyond me... maybe they have a new kernel add-in that determines if the manufacturer has paid them for a certificate of compliance?

---

*Windows* 7 64-bit,
*KVM*:  ATEN CS62US,
*Mouse*: Aula Ghost Shark,
*Keyboard*: MS Natural Ergonomic 4000